# Angular directive require - controller not found

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to have a directive require a controller that is defined separately (e.g. outside of directives). All the examples I've seen have been chained directives using the controller function/option.

What I want to do is define a controller per usual norms, and then have a directive that will be nested in that controllers markup require it and gain access to it.

Like so:

```
app.controller('MyController', function() {
    $scope.awesomeProperty = 11;
});


app.directive('someDirective', function() {
  return {
    scope: {},
    require: '^MyController',
    link: function($scope, el, attrs, ctrl) {
        console.log(ctrl.awesomeProperty); //11
    }
  }
});
```

However, this throws a ctreq error - it can't find the controller. Note I'm using "^" to denote ancestor, because in all cases the outer containing element will contain the controller.

Am I just misunderstanding this? I've double triple checked spelling, etc. Are "controllers" in this case different from actual "angular controllers" that are only defined via directives?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: That's not how `require` works; [`require`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-require-) is for including other directives (and injecting their controllers). Looks like you just want to set the directive's `controller` property instead, eg `controller: 'MyController'`

Comment: So, how do you use it to say "I want the link function's "ctrl" to be assigned the instance of "MyController"'?

Comment: Ugh. That is stupidly simple I shoudl have just tried it.

Comment: I'll state for the record that angular's docs are terribly confusing on this. They keep using the word "controller" when they refer to directives. It was confusing me and this makes sense.

Comment: The [`$compile`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) doco is probably the most verbose (and confusing) but it's worth reading thoroughly